# Overriding CSS variable in Svelte

Tags: css, svelte, sveltekit, css-variables

I'm trying to set opacity of HSLA background color dynamically using CSS variables.
First I created a variable `--color` for color, which has `--alpha` variable in it as alpha. It works, but I am not able to override the `--alpha` variable at element level. The `--alpha: .5` on `h1` tag is applied to the element, but i am not seeing the transparency on the element.

REPL here: https://svelte.dev/repl/d4e15ba129324149915c2e124eeecb76?version=3.59.1

```
<script>
    let name = 'world';
</script>

<h1 style="--alpha: .5">Hello {name}!</h1>

<style>
    :global(:root) {
        --alpha: 1;
        --color: hsla(225, 50%, 50%, var(--alpha));
    }
    h1 {
        background-color: var(--color);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the variable is defined on a different element, higher in the tree, the change to `--alpha` will not affect `--color` as that is resolved at a different level with a different `--alpha` value.

One way around that would be to define the variables on all elements in the component (would not recommend using `:global` if it can be avoided, if some children in another component rely on this it may be necessary though).

```css
* { 
  --alpha: 1;
  --color: hsla(225, 50%, 50%, var(--alpha));
}
```

For scoped styles the selector is turned into just a class selector in the form `.svelte-[hash]` but for global styles it might be best to avoid this approach if it negatively impacts performance.

A more optimized way if you need `:global` would be to move just the color declaration to a special class which then needs to be applied on elements where the `--color` is being referenced (in this case the `h1` or any child components):

```css
:global(.custom-color) {
  --color: hsla(225, 50%, 50%, var(--alpha));
}
```

If you extract all other color components (hue, saturation, lightness) and drop `--color` altogether, you could avoid this situation, though you also would always have to spell out a lengthy `hsla` definition everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's the best approach for you as I don't know what you are trying to do but one solution would be setting the CSS variable using Javascript:

```
<script>
    let alpha = 0.5;
    let root = document.querySelector(":root")
    $: root.style.setProperty('--alpha', alpha);
</script>
```

Now whenever you change the alpha value the `root.style.setProperty('--alpha', alpha);` will rerun achieving what I think you want.

Comment: Thank you. But I am able to modify `--color` variable on an element. Updated the REPL.

`<h2 style="--color: red">Subhead </h2>`

Does this mean "nested variables" can't be modifed?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying by "can't be modified using CSS" ... but you absolutely can change the values of CSS custom properties with CSS alone? Changes to their values cascade down and are inherited by child elements just like with most other CSS properties.   https://jsfiddle.net/exunfha9/1/

Comment: @diopside I didn't know that was possible... thank you for informing me I will edit the answer.